# Is there precedent or are there procedures for a US president refusing to concede to an electoral defeat?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election, contested-election

I am wondering what would happen if an incumbent US President were to lose a presidential election, but refuse to accept the result and to concede defeat (even after any legitimate challenges and appeals have failed)? Thus, the incumbent President refuses to leave the White House.

Is there any precedent for such an event? Are there any established processes in place to deal with such a situation?

Comment: In your scenario, how definite is the "loss"? Are you saying that the challenger won unambiguously and everyone (except for the president) accepts it? Or are you imagining a scenario more like the 2000 election where a critical state is _very close_, with evidence of possible irregularities? To put it another way, are you only asking about a straight-up coup attempt, or an attempt to muddy the waters of an ambiguous result?

Comment: @divibisan I reversed your edit. I think o.m.'s [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/41227/25684) is good and I don't want it invalidated.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't try to answer the question using comments. If you would like to answer, please write a real answer which adheres to our quality standards.

Comment: I wonder if someone passed this question on to Nancy Pelosi. This weekend the NY Times reported that she's worried that Trump won't accept a defeat in 2020 unless there's a huge margin. https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/04/us/politics/nancy-pelosi.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is [no precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_transition) for a president refusing to leave in the United states.  There are Presidential transition laws that have been amended fairly regularly. These laws grant newly elected presidents and their team office space and clearances. The [General Services Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Services_Administration) is responsible for provisioning space for the newly elected president and transition team, they are separate from the executive branch so the president can't directly interfere with this process. The Oath of Office ceremony on January 20th is the start to the new presidency, at which time the previous president has no real authority, there is no requirement that the current president resign. The level of force used in evicting a reluctant president would likely be a call by the new president.

As for a scenario where a president actively tries to stop the inauguration of a new president, in theory no one would follow such orders, as their ultimate oath is to the constitution itself not the President. This is a grey area of not following unlawful orders, which is a common theoretical position, but hard to enforce in practice. An act of preventing a transition of power would likely rise to the level that most people required to prevent such a thing would be uncooperative, but that opinion relies on a lot of hypothetical situations.

Comment: "It is the longest peaceful transition of power in the world": can you provide a source for that? I suspect that the UK (as the successor state of Great Britain, and before that, England & Wales) and others (maybe Iceland?) have been doing this for longer.

Comment: Is it the longest peaceful transition of power in the world? The UK has had peaceful transitions since 1688 AFAIK, which is rather longer than the USA has existed. Also, the attempted secession of several US states during the Buchanan–Lincoln transition period, while not involving violence in Washington D.C., rather complicates the claim.

Comment: @JohnDallman technically, numerous British territories attempted to violently secede from the British Empire between 1688 and today, including the US itself.

Comment: @JonathanReez And some of those [committed violence in London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfridges,_Oxford_Street_bombing_1975).

Comment: Andorra has had peaceful transitions of power for over a thousand years and counting.

Comment: @JonathanReez I would say "transition of power" means from one candidate to another and doesn't include territories disagreeing, it's more about the candidates. However I'm sure there is some way to define it such that USA technically is the longest, but that seems cheap.

Comment: The idea of preventing the inauguration is interesting, but the ceremony itself is mostly unnecessary.  The constitution requires that the incoming president swear an oath or make an affirmation, but any judge can administer that, and probably several other officers as well.  The outgoing president couldn't realistically prevent the incoming one from doing it.  Also, the GSA is [part of the executive branch](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/40/301) and its administrator [reports to the president](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/40/302).

Comment: @gerrit If you discount the revolution of 1933, of course...  With that said, the US also had a civil war, so...

Comment: One might raise the Venetian Republic as potentially a longer period of peaceful transfers of power, too. I don't have my Norwich to hand, but they had a good several centuries or so there, if I recall...

Comment: Perhaps if you limit it to democracies, US would win, since the UK was a monarchy until a century ago.

Comment: @Barmar You could also count the number, since the US transfers power every 4-8 years (with one exception) while the UK transfers power on the death of a monarch.

Comment: @gerrit - "After King Henry III of Navarre became King Henry IV of France, he issued an edict in 1607 establishing the King of France and the Bishop of Urgell as co-princes of Andorra. ... The French head of state—whether king, emperor, or president—has continued to serve as a co-prince of Andorra ever since. [Co-Princes of Andorra - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-Princes_of_Andorra). Perhaps technically, but I'm not sure how much independence it really enjoys since it's existence is at the decree of a (long dead) foreign king, and it's ruled by the leaders of 2 foreign powers.

Comment: @gerrit Don't forget [Boris Skossyreff](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Skossyreff)

Comment: Netherlands have had centuries of peaceful transition of power starting in 1581 (with some interruptions when under foreign occupation of course).

Comment: @jwenting ?? You can't discount interruptions - that's the whole point!

Comment: Anything Trump related was "pure hypothetical and unlikely" just a decade ago. I wouldn't rule out civil militia stepping in, and an actual civil war starting. It only makes sense.

Comment: An old answer, but this seems relevant: https://www.ted.com/talks/van_jones_what_if_a_us_presidential_candidate_refuses_to_concede_after_an_election

Answer (score 39):

At 12:00 Noon on January 20, the incoming President would accede to power and would at that point be able to decide who is and is not allowed on the White House Complex.  The former president at that point could be ordered to leave by the sitting president, and would be removed by the Secret Service if he refused (in reality they would probably try to find some way to remove him with the least public fanfare possible).  Although former presidents are entitled to a Secret Service detail, that detail cannot protect them from lawful detainment or arrest.

Comment: Indeed, the former president's own secret service detail could effect the arrest.

Comment: "_Although former presidents are entitled to a Secret Service detail..._" The, just now, former president would have Secret Service protection, but during the Clinton administration, the law was changed so that former presidents are only entitled to 10 years of Secret Service protection after leaving office, rather the the lifetime protection afforded to previous presidents. That law went into effect starting with G.W Bush.

Comment: @RonMaupin Aha. So even  if the Secret Service sides with the old president, you just have to wait ten years and _then_ you can evict them from the White House! 

Comment: @DavidRicherby I suspect, if a Secret Service detail sides with an ex-president and unlawfully occupies the White House with him, then it probably wouldn't cause a major conscience problem for them, if they also violate this 10-years rule.

Comment: @RonMaupin that law is void and it's back to lifetime protection (in particular, this happened before there was any example of someone losing protection after being out for 10 years). See the last section of en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Former_Presidents_Act.

Comment: @KCd That would seem to be illegal because it affects the president that signed the law. That was the reason that the original 10-year restriction didn't apply to President Clinton. Changes are supposed to apply to the next [Congress, Administration, etc], although it would seem that only the hardcore tax reformers may object, but that is still a possibility.

Comment: @RonMaupin you raise a fair point, but perhaps it does not apply when the purpose is only to overturn a previous law and return to how things were before. For example, when the 21st amendment repealed the 18th amendment did that repeal  *not* apply to the current President and members of Congress at that time, so they would have still been subject directly to the 18th amendment? I agree that's a bit of a silly premise, but I can't think of a more practical example at the moment.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm pretty sure the only thing that rule applies to is the salary of Congressmen due to the 27th Amendment.  The Former Presidents Act as passed by Clinton just specified that it only applied to Presidents inaugurated after January 1, 1997, so not Clinton.

Comment: The public inauguration ceremony is held on the 21st if the 20th falls on Sunday, but the term still ends on the 20th, and the oath of office has historically been administered in a private ceremony on the 20th.

Comment: @GraySheep if a former president's Secret Service detail did that, they would be fired or at least relieved of duty for failing to follow orders.  (The former president is no longer their boss or even in their chain of command, which runs to the sitting president.)  Then they too would be subject to removal from the White House for trespassing.

Comment: @phoog I don't see any instances of that happening after the date was changed to January 20, but it does look like it happened twice while the date was March 4 so I'll remove that note from my answer.

Comment: @phoog Possibly they would be also charged on some quite serious laws like high treason, threating the constitutional order or similar. However, if they would do this, they would do this also knowing that this can happen. But I think this all is quite hyphothetical - the constitutional order of the U.S. is one of the most stable in the world history. Unfortunately, it does not mean that they would be so nice.

Comment: @GraySheep no. Treason is defined by the constitution, and this isn't it.  There is no crime of "threatening the constitutional order."  There's no need to be so dramatic.  A former president who tried to pull such a stunt is trespassing, and a Secret Service agent who refuses to expel him is insubordinate.  It's just petty and childish.

Comment: "I don't see any instances of that happening after the date was changed to January 20": Eisenhower's second inauguration, January 20 and 21, 1957: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_inauguration_of_Dwight_D._Eisenhower

Answer (score 29):

<s>I find it completely unthinkable that a President would acknowledge the electoral defeat and still refuse to leave. The much more thinkable scenario is that a President disputes the election results. There is a tradition in the United States that the defeated candidate "concedes" the election with a call to the winner.</s>
(The question has been edited to answer this part.)

**Imagine the concession does not happen.**

Instead, both candidates claim victory. They send lawyers to challenge the count in many or most states. Elected, partisan state officials get into the fray. Isolated cases of vote fraud are documented in a more or less credible way. Conspiracy theories mushroom. To complicate things further, imagine that one Supreme Court judge has retired or became medically unfit, and that the remaining ones are deadlocked 4-4.

**The result would be utter chaos and an unpredictable outcome.**

One might guess that the incumbent has an advantage in such a scenario, but it also matters where the majority of the State governments and the Federal judges stand.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant a scenario such a that you describe, where the president refused to accept the outcome. I will edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: In theory, it's Congress that decides whether to accept a state's electoral college votes. Not that it wouldn't still be a constitutional crisis for counting or not counting disputed votes.

Comment: @pboss3010 "The President of the Senate shall, in the presence of the Senate and House of Representatives, open all the certificates and the votes shall then be counted." There is no provision for congress accepting the votes or not; if the VP refuses to open the ballots, or anyone tries to prevent the person who receives the most electoral votes from being sworn into office, that's not just a constitutional crisis, it's an attempted (or if successful, actual) coup.

Comment: The losing candidate can also just accept the loss without actively conceding.  But the question assumes that the incumbent has lost (that is, after any legal challenges), and it's noon on January 20th, and the incumbent refuses to acknowledge that someone else is president.  Rather than the state governments and federal judges, I think the allies such an incumbent would need would have to be (at least significant portions of) the Secret Service and perhaps other armed officers of the federal government.  It seems rather unlikely.

Comment: No need for imagination - you already have Bush vs Gore. With media support, Bush's team managed to spin a disputed result where the presidency was literally undecided into "our guy won, and it's unfair to question the legitimacy of that win". It's incorrect to say that challenging the count is a problem - in fact it's an essential countermeasure to impartially turn a disputed result into a fair result. If a recount process can't be managed in a timely manner, it casts serious doubt on the correctness of the original count.

Comment: In order for both candidates to claim victory, the recorded outcome would need to be close enough for at least some degree of reasonable doubt. That isn't what the OP asked - the OP asked what would happen if one candidate had a clear victory and the (possibly incumbent) loser refuses to acknowledges it.

Comment: @Shadur, what is unreasonable doubt to one person can be reasonable to another. I tried very much not to name names in this hypothetical, but look at claims about the scope of illegal voters during the last presidential election.

Comment: @Kevin your comment should be an Answer.

Comment: @phoog They'd need the support of the military, the FBI and ATF might also help since they have all the military surplus toys.  The Secret Service is pretty small in comparison.  As an aside to the answer, if the main contention were one or two states the legislature in those states could possibly resolve the deadlock by instructing the electors who to vote for.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I am assuming that the military is not going to attack the White House.  A small contingent of Secret Service agents willing to use their firearms to keep people away would probably be sufficient to keep the president in there until they run out of food.  It would be folly for the people trying to get the former president out to shoot at anyone.  As to the electors, the assumption of the question is that the incumbent lost.  Congress has counted the votes and announced the result.  This is beyond the point of any deadlock or other electoral maneuvers.

Comment: In case of a 4-4 "tie" by the SCOTUS, a lower court's decision stands.  I put "tie" in quotes there because it's not a tie. It doesn't produce lack of clarity.  It's a decision.

Comment: @grovkin, it will be the lower courts' decisions, plural. Possibly many lower courts' decisions on part of the problem, mutually inconsistent.

Comment: @o.m. no.  circuit courts have non-overlapping geographic area of jurisdiction.  they would decide on any state-specific issues.

Comment: @grovkin, so in half the states hanging chads count, and in the other half they are dismissed? A recipe for discontent.

Comment: @o.m. which is exactly how it stands in the US. Different states, even different counties, have different laws and legal frameworks relating to them. What's legal on one side of the road may be illegal on the other side of the road, literally.

Comment: @Graham you mean Gore refused to accept he had lost and insisted on eternal recounts in the hope that one would give him a 1 vote majority. In the end the courts stepped in to stop the perpetual recounts that'd other wise have gone on for years, or until Bush'd given in to bullying for the good of the country.

Comment: @jwenting By "perpetual" you mean "the single recount permitted by electoral rules"? And by "lost" you mean "substantial issues with the voting process in a close election which made this a valid issue"? As I said, if you've won fairly, you've no reason to be afraid of having the result checked; and if the process means the result can't be checked, that's a failure to have sound democracy in the country, not the fault of the candidate.

Comment: @Graham There were repeated recounts in Florida in the 2000 election cycle in several counties. Gore demanded a recount, lost the recount, sued to get another recount, lost that one too, demanded a recount of that recount, repeat ad infinitum (or in this case until the USSC stepped in and put a stop to the nonsense). He was a very bad loser from the start.

Comment: According to the latest events (you wisely mentioned) - death of one of the judges, your answer become even more interesting.

Comment: The incumbent's position is irrelevant. The constitution defines what happens not the incumbent's position. If court challenges don't alter the College vote tally, then the winner is the next president. If the tally is tied, the House of Representatives decides. There is no circumstance where the refusal of the incumbent to concede matters.

Comment: @matt_black, imagine a scenario where state legislatures and state officialts throw out some results, federal judges decide inconsistently, the supreme court is deadlocked. Both the incumbent and the challenger claim victory. This would **not** be an orderly process. and it matters who can send the Feds to enforce some but not all rulings of lower courts.

Comment: @o.m. It doesn't matter whether different courts decide differently. All that matters is the court decision in the highest court. The decisions might be a mess and people might not like them, but the rules are clear about which ruling is definitive.

Comment: @matt_black, it seems that you have more faith in the political culture of the US than I do right now. Let's hope that it happens as you say, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: You're also forgetting one of the key players here.  One of the biggest factors in such a chaotic debacle would be who the US military decided to support.  Ultimately a piece of paper is just a piece of paper.  The idea contained within it are what give it power.  So it is with the rules: the rules matter and are powerful because a bunch of people believe in them enough that they decide to enforce them.  I'll put it this way - In this situation, if the army says 'you're both disqualified, we're establishing a caretaker administration to oversee new elections' ... who's going to stop them?

Comment: @TonDay, I seriously doubt that the Army would intervene. The more likely (but still unlikely) matter would be armed law enforcement, e.g. Marshalls seizing ballots or Feds trying to arrest the Secret Service (or vice versa).

Answer (score 15):

Since the question assumes that the incumbent has lost, the talk of court challenges and the like is not relevant.  If such a challenges were to succeed, the  incumbent would be the winner.

Once Congress has finished with its 12th-amendment duties in determining the winner of the election, the result is decided.  It is not necessary for defeated candidates to concede.  Courts are generally unwilling to review political matters such as this.

If Congress determined that the incumbent president had lost the election, then, as a matter of law, that person would cease to be president at noon on January 20th.  Refusing to leave the White House doesn't change that, and the new president's inability to enter the White House would not deprive him or her of the office of president.

By remaining in the White House without authorization, the outgoing president would be liable for conviction under [18 USC 1752](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1752) and a fine of up to $100,000 and/or imprisonment for up to one year (or a fine of up to $250,000 and imprisonment for up to 10 years if they resisted with weapons or if the resistance cause serious injury).

> Is there any precedent for such an event? Are there any established processes in place to deal with such a situation?

As others have noted, there is certainly no precedent for this.  I suppose the Secret Service probably has some procedure for this, but if they do it is probably, well, secret.  In practice, as others have noted, the incoming president would likely decide what to do based on political considerations.

Comment: "The election of the president is certified by Congress." There is no certification (assuming a majority winner), the VP "shall" open the certificates, the votes "shall then be counted," and "The person having the greatest Number of votes for President, shall be the President." Anyone who can add can total up the votes, and any attempt to prevent the person with the most votes from being sworn in is an attempted coup, and we have to hope that the secret service, capitol police, and military back the constitution rather than the usurper.

Comment: Although most, if not all presidents have rabid supporters, it is hard to imagine enough insane people to make such a coup successful.  But USA does seem to be heading in that direction (on BOTH sides).

Comment: @Kevin it is true that the constitution does not refer to congress's role as "certifying" the result of the election, and the [transcript of the most recent vote counting session](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/2017/01/06/house-section/article/H185-8) also does not, but the [daily digest from that day](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/2017/01/06) does. Regardless of the verb used, the election result must be determined by Congress. But the question assumes the result, so these details don't affect the main point of the answer. I've rewritten the opening.

Answer (score 8):

After January 20, following the election year, the president is no longer president. It's not a matter of choice, or concession. That's the law. Any 'orders' given by a former president after January 20 have no meaning.

The US military leaders are bound by law to uphold not the president, but the Constitution of the US. If the Constitution, or laws framed by it, state that a person is no longer president, then the military is required to ignore anything they say.

Generally speaking, presidents maintain the dignity of the office, and the stability of the nation, by being gracious in departure.

The only thing a president could do is subject themselves to the spectacle of being forcibly removed from the White House.

Comment: and gluing the keys of all the computer keyboards so they can't be used... wouldn't be the first time...

Comment: Supposedly, the Clinton staffers removed all the W keys from keyboards before they left the white house in 2000. And I recall seeing a cartoon of Harry Truman refusing to leave the WH before his other boot was found.

Answer (score 4):

> I am wondering what would happen if an incumbent US President lost a presidential election, but refused to accept the result and to concede defeat (and thus, refused to leave the White House)?

Like the other answers said, in the case of a completely unambiguous loss and the president alone contesting its validity, the Secret Service could be expected to remove the incumbent in time for the winner to move into the White House.

A few things they've left out:

- In such a case, the president would obviously be experiencing massive psychological impairment. Everyone might try to just ride it out until the new administration, but the American presidency has become very imperial. There are dozens of things such a paranoid incumbent might order that would require his **removal under the XXV Amendment**.
- **It's standard fare for presidents to lose the election**. 5 of the last 40 lost the popular vote (including 2 of the last 3), and another 5 won by less than 2% of the vote. Most police aren't federal and the Armed Forces swear their oaths to the Constitution, not to the offices. The Constitution says that the Electoral College is what matters, not the actual election itself. The usual thing for unhappy losers to do, though, is write think pieces and propose reforms, not try to hold onto the Oval Office chair for as long as possible.
- It's possible that the incumbent—like the incumbents in many other countries—might have **military allies** that would make this more than a bout of insanity. Because of the oaths, that would likely require thinking that the opponent's term of office would do more harm to the Constitution than neglecting its terms would: Bernie probably isn't enough, but something like a one-man-one-vote-one-time Communist Party victory might. Someone who won the election but did so on a platform that essentially supports nixing the current Constitution in favor of something else. In that case, pretty much all bets are off: you might have them reinstitute fair elections fairly soon once they felt they would win them, you might end up with a decades-long military oligarchy like Turkey or Taiwan, or you might end up with a dictatorship testing the organizational skills of II Amendment enthusiasts.

Comment: It is an interesting question, that organizing a revolution, with 2nd amendment weapons, against such a "president" is constitutional or not.

Comment: @GraySheep At that point we're out-of-bounds of the Constitution and playing a different game. Whoever wins under the law of the jungle determines the next constitution.

Comment: If we assume that the president is willing to throw a coup, why do we assume that his supporters will interpret their oaths in sane ways, or even keep them at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way the US Constitution works the presidential election that is exceedingly unlikely.  The election of https://www.rbhayes.org/hayes/disputed-election-of-1876/ shows why.

> Tilden won the popular vote and led in the electoral college, but 19
>   votes from three Republican-controlled states (Louisiana, Florida, and
>   South Carolina) remained disputed. Oregon's count was also challenged.
>   Allegations of widespread voter fraud forced Congress to set up a
>   special electoral commission to determine the winner, composed of
>   fifteen congressmen and Supreme Court justices. The commission finally
>   announced their decision only two days before the inauguration. The
>   vote was 8-7 along party lines to award the disputed electoral college
>   votes to Hayes, making him the winner.

Basically it does not matter whether a presidential candidate concedes defeat or not.
If Congress is on his or her side, then the candidate is not defeated - despite everything else.
If Congress is against the candidate, then the candidate can not possibly win..